# Как работать с OCR библиотекой Google Vision(Mobile Vision)

Tags: java, android, распознавание-символов, google-vision

Хочу сделать приложение которое бы сканировало числа и выводило их в приложение.
Из библиотек я знаю Teseract, ABBYY, и Google Vision(Mobile Vision).

> ABBYY сразу уходит на 2 план, так как он работает с интернетом,
>   лицензия нужна на него даже если trial версия.
>
> Teseract не умеет работать с RealmTime. Он нужен чтобы сделать снимок
>   и из снимка получить данные.
>
> А вот Google Vision уже другое дело. И без инета работает, и быстро
>   сканит. Вот тоьлко беда с АПИ.

1) Я не знаю как установить в CameraSource параметр из Камеры `Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE`.

2) Не знаю как можно установить свою ширину и высоту для сканирования. Изменить размер SurfaceView оказалось не достаточно. А метод setRequestedPreviewSize() толком не дает нужного результата.

Щяс стою в тупике.

Есть ли способ решить мою проблему в Google Vision или же может поможете найти хорошую библиотеку чтобы можно было туда добаить весь вышеописанный функицонал.

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ вот тут. Оставлю вдруг кому пригодиться

https://gist.github.com/Gericop/7de0b9fdd7a444e53b5a
*P.S

Хотел закрыть вопрос указав эту ссылку, да вот только нет такой возможности на SO. Жаль*